# Python number guessing game not displaying feedback correctly. What's the problem?

Tags: python-3.x

So I tried to make a game where the computer chooses a random 4 digit number out of 10 given numbers. The computer then compares the guess of the user with the random chosen code, and will give feedback accordingly:

- G = correct digit that is correctly placed
- C = correct digit, but incorrectly placed
- F = the digit isn't in the code chosen by the computer

However, the feedback doesn't always output correctly. 
Fox example, when I guess 9090, the feedback I get is F C F, while the feedback should consist of 4 letters.... How can I fix this?

```py
#chooses the random pincode that needs to be hacked
import random
pincode = [
    '1231', '9997', '8829', '6765',  '9114', '5673', '0103', '4370', '8301', '1022'
]

name = None

#Main code for the game
def main():
    global code
    global guess

    #Chooses random pincode
    code = random.choice(pincode)

    #Sets guessestaken to 0
    guessesTaken = 0

    while guessesTaken < 10:

        #Makes sure every turn, an extra guess is added
        guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

        #Asks for user input
        print("This is turn " + str(guessesTaken) + ". Try a code!")
        guess = input()

        #Easteregg codes
        e1 = "1955"
        e2 = "1980"

        #Checks if only numbers have been inputted
        if guess.isdigit() == False:
            print("You can only use numbers, remember?")
            guessesTaken = guessesTaken - 1
            continue

        #Checks whether guess is 4 numbers long
        if len(guess) != len(code):
            print("The code is only 4 numbers long! Try again!")
            guessesTaken = guessesTaken - 1
            continue

        #Checks the code
        if guess == code:

            #In case the user guesses the code in 1 turn
            if (guessesTaken) == 1:
                print("Well done, " + name + "! You've hacked the code in " +
                      str(guessesTaken) + " turn!")

            #In cases the user guesses the code in more than 1 turn
            else:
                print("Well done, " + name + "! You've hacked the code in " +
                      str(guessesTaken) + " turns!")
            return

        #Sets empty list for the feedback on the user inputted code
        feedback = []
        nodouble = []

        #Iterates from 0 to 4
        for i in range(4):

            #Compares the items in the list to eachother
            if guess[i] == code[i]:

                #A match means the letter G is added to feedback
                feedback.append("G")
                nodouble.append(guess[i])

            #Checks if the guess number is contained in the code
            elif guess[i] in code:

                #Makes sure the position of the numbers isn't the same
                if guess[i] != code[i]:
                    if guess[i] not in nodouble:

                        #The letter is added to feedback[]  if there's a match
                        feedback.append("C")
                        nodouble.append(guess[i])

            #If the statements above are false, this is executed
            elif guess[i] not in code:

                #No match at all means an F is added to feedback[]
                feedback.append("F")
                nodouble.append(guess[i])

        #Easteregg
        if guess != code and guess == e1 or guess == e2:
            print("Yeah!")
            guessesTaken = guessesTaken - 1
        else:
            print(*feedback, sep=' ')


main()
```

You can try the game here: 
https://repl.it/@optimusrobertus/Hack-The-Pincode

EDIT 2:
[Here, you can see an example of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3LoU.png)

Comment: I ran the code on repl, and gave 9090 as the guess code and it printed 4 letters of feedback. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dileep Huh, that's really weird.... Because when just now when I inputed 9090, I got G F F as feedback......

Comment: @Dileep I added a link to a screenshot of what I mean in my post.

Comment: I think I got the issue, there is a logical mistake Robert. Try running for `code="8829"` and `guess="9090"`. You will encounter the issue because of the way you are handling the occurrence of same digit multiple times. I would suggest you to create a bit-array of size 10 which will store the count of occurrence of each digit (0-9) in `code`. Then, for each digit in `guessed`, decrease the count of that digit. Let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. Let me know if it works.

```
from random import randint


class PinCodeGame(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._attempt = 10
        self._code = ['1231', '9997', '8829', '6765', '9114', '5673', '0103', '4370', '8301',
                    '1022']
        self._easterEggs = ['1955', '1980', '1807', '0609']

    def introduction(self):
        print("Hi there stranger! What do I call you? ")
        player_name = input()
        return player_name

    def show_game_rules(self):
        print("10 turns. 4 numbers. The goal? Hack the pincode.")
        print(
            "For every number in the pincode you've come up with, I'll tell you whether it is correct AND correctly placed (G), correct but placed incorrectly (C) or just plain wrong (F)."
        )

    def tutorial_needed(self):
        # Asks for tutorial
        print("Do you want a tutorial? (yes / no)")
        tutorial = input().lower()

        # While loop for giving the tutorial
        while tutorial != "no" or tutorial != "yes":
            # Gives tutorial
            if tutorial == "yes":
                return True

            # Skips tutorial
            elif tutorial == "no":
                return False

            # Checks if the correct input has been given
            else:
                print("Please answer with either yes or no.")
                tutorial = input()

    def generate_code(self):
        return self._code[randint(0, len(self._code))]

    def is_valid_guess(self, guess):
        return len(guess) == 4 and guess.isdigit()

    def play(self, name):
        attempts = 0
        code = self.generate_code()
        digits = [code.count(str(i)) for i in range(10)]

        while attempts < self._attempt:
            attempts += 1
            print("Attempt #", attempts)
            guess = input()
            hints = ['F'] * 4
            count_digits = [i for i in digits]
            if self.is_valid_guess(guess):
                if guess == code or guess in self._easterEggs:
                    print("Well done, " + name + "! You've hacked the code in " +
                        str(attempts) + " turn!")
                    return True, code
                else:
                    for i, digit in enumerate(guess):
                        index = int(digit)
                        if count_digits[index] > 0 and code[i] == digit:
                            count_digits[index] -= 1
                            hints[i] = 'G'
                        elif count_digits[index] > 0:
                            count_digits[index] -= 1
                            hints[i] = 'C'
                    print(*hints, sep=' ')
            else:
                print("Invalid input, guess should be 4 digits long.")
                attempts -= 1
        return False, code


def main():
    # initialise game
    game = PinCodeGame()
    player_name = game.introduction()
    print("Hi, " + player_name)
    if game.tutorial_needed():
        game.show_game_rules()
    while True:
        result, code = game.play(player_name)
        if result:
            print(
                "Oof. You've beaten me.... Do you want to be play again (and be beaten this time)? (yes / no)")
        else:
            print("Hahahahaha! You've lost! The correct code was " + code +
                ". Do you want to try again, and win this time? (yes / no)")
        play_again = input().lower()
        if play_again == "no":
            return


main()
```